# Understand the use of dx and dy commands in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to NetLogo and I'm in doubt about 2 Netlogo commands.

Could someone help me understand the dx and dy commands? I read the description in the NetLogo dictionary. But, I didn't quite understand what it does.

What's the difference between using a move with dx and dy and without?

Thanks in advance!

A simplified example taken from a book with application in NetLogo:

```
turtles-own
[
  real_x ;; the real x coordinate dist from origin ie ignoring wrapping around world
  real_y ;; the real y coordinate dist from origin ie ignoring wrapping around world
]

to setup
  here
  create-turtles 1
  ask turtles
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   ; set real-x xcor
   ; set real-y ycor
  ]
  reset ticks
end

to go
  move
  tick
end

to move
  ;; using dy and dx
  ; ask turtles
  ; [
  ; set heading random-float 360
  ; set real_x real_x + dx
  ; set real_y real_y + dy
  ; fd 1
  ; ]
  
   ask turtles
  [
    set heading random-float 360
    fd 1
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dx is the ***d***ifference in the ***x***-coordinate if the turtle move forward 1 unit at its current heading. Same thing for dy and the y-coordinate.

Mathematically: tan(heading) = dy/dx

Geometrically:
[image]